# cross-platform API to play audio files in console-based application

Tags: audio, cross-platform, console-application

Which programming languages have cross-platform API to play audio files in console-based applications?

Comment: This is the corresponding question, asked for Haskell: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841999/how-to-play-an-audio-file-from-haskell-code-cross-platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost all programming languages have bindings to `SDL` and `SDL_mixer`, the latter has a [relatively simple API](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/docs/SDL_mixer.html#SEC52) to play audio files in common format.