# How to play an audio file from Haskell code, cross-platform

Tags: linux, windows, haskell, audio

I’m writing a Haskell command line application that runs on Linux, Windows and OS X. I now have to play audio files (`.wav`, `.ogg` and `.mp3`) from it. How would I go about implementing a function

```
playAudioFile :: FilePath -> IO ()
```

or even better

```
playAudio :: ByteString -> IO ()
```

that simply works on all system?

(I’m happy to invoke common command line tools and also don’t mind bundling them for the Windows distribution.)

Comment: This is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005592/play-a-wav-file-with-haskell but I need to play common file formats besides `.wav`.

Comment: I'd be (pleasantly) surprised if this is actually possible. I mean, without manually writing bindings to some existing C library yourself...

Comment: Hmm, maybe http://stackoverflow.com/a/14011063/946226 actually points to the right direction; SDL seems to support MP3 and Ogg in [Graphics.UI.SDL.Mixer.Music](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/SDL-mixer-0.6.1/docs/Graphics-UI-SDL-Mixer-Music.html).

Comment: gstreamer runs on OSX, Windows and Linux, and has support for a lot of different formats, so that may be worth a look.

Comment: I’m a bit worried about getting a nice Windows-friendly and self-contained package out of that, but at least it’s a possibility.

Comment: I guess ffmpeg is another option

Comment: ffmpeg even comes with a nice `ffplay` binary, but it’s 30MB in size as a static binary – a bit too much for just playing audio. I guess it also contains lot of video and encoding stuff...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the code I came up with, using SDL-1.2:

```
module PlaySound (withSound, playSound) where

import Control.Monad
import System.IO
import System.Directory
import Data.Foldable
import Control.Exception
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B
import Foreign.ForeignPtr

import Graphics.UI.SDL as SDL
import Graphics.UI.SDL.Mixer as Mix

withSound :: IO a -> IO a
withSound = bracket_ init cleanup
  where
    init = do
        SDL.init [SDL.InitAudio]
        getError >>= traverse_ putStrLn
        ok <- Mix.tryOpenAudio Mix.defaultFrequency Mix.AudioS16LSB 2  4096
        unless ok $
            putStrLn "Failed to open SDL audio device"

    cleanup = do
        Mix.closeAudio
        SDL.quit

playSound :: B.ByteString -> IO ()
playSound content = do
        dir <- getTemporaryDirectory
        (tmp, h) <- openTempFile dir "sdl-input"
        B.hPutStr h content
        hClose h

        mus <- Mix.loadMUS tmp
        Mix.playMusic mus 1
        wait

        -- This would double-free the Music, as it is also freed via a
        -- finalizer
        --Mix.freeMusic mus
        finalizeForeignPtr mus
        removeFile tmp

wait :: IO ()
wait = do
    SDL.delay 50
    stillPlaying <- Mix.playingMusic
    when stillPlaying wait
```

The program in the end works fine, but

- compiling the SDL bindings under Windows is tricky. I followed [this nice explanation on how to do it](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/08/13/haskell-sdl-bindings-windows/)
- the SDL bindings for SDL-1.2 seem to be unmaintained and [do not even compile with GHC-7.8 or newer](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.beginners/13663). I didn’t notice at first, because my distribution (Debian) patches around such issues, but it means that my users cannot easily `cabal install` the dependencies any more.
- there are bindings for SDL-2, but none for the SDL_mixer, which I need here (I believe).

So I’ll happily read better answers.

Comment: In the end, I used a dedicated binary using `SDL`, to avoid the dependency on the SDL-1.2 Haskell bindings, which are unmaintained. That [code is written in C](https://github.com/entropia/tip-toi-reveng/blob/master/playmus/playmus.c), simply because the example code that came with SDL_mixer was almost good enough.

Comment: I think it would be nice to have a simple way of playing mp3s or wavs without requiring SDL and SDL_mixer, or at least hiding those details.

I just sent a patch to the maintainer of SDL_mixer to get it to compile with GHC 7.8 (it was giving me a linking error). I'm curious: what problem did you have?

There are SDL2 bindings for mixer, see https://github.com/jdeseno/hs-sdl2-mixer. I used those for Keera Studios' Magic Cookies! and they worked fine (with minor adjustments to compile them for Android).

Comment: I don’t remember, but probably the same as mentioned in http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.beginners/13663. 

About `sd2-mixer`: That is not yet on hackage, that must have prevented me from using them.

Comment: The new version of sdl-mixer (SDL 1.2) is on hackage now: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/SDL-mixer

I can verify that it works with GHC 7.8.

Comment: And, in case it helps anyone, for a trivial example, clone this gist with git.

https://gist.github.com/ivanperez-keera/4155135931eb48201b6f

Comment: Now, in 2018, there are SDL2 bindings for the SDL_mixer. Example code for wrapping it to play (wav, mp3, ogg, flac) using a filename here: https://github.com/Qqwy/Haskell-sound-playing (that repo includes the dependencies required, just clone it and run `stack build`)

Answer (score 0):

A new option is the `proteaaudio`  Haskell library:

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/proteaaudio

> ProteaAudio is a minimalist stereo audio mixer/playback library for
>
> - Linux
> - MacOS
> - Windows
>
> Supported audio formats:
>
> - Wav
> - Ogg
> - Raw linear PCM